# If elements are mutually independent then the whole set is linearly independent or not

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $\{ a,b,c,d\}\subseteq \mathbb R^5$ satisfies the following:
>
> - $\{a,b,c\},\{a,b,d\}$ and $\{c,d\}$ are linearly independent sets.
>
> Can we say from here that the set $\{a,b,c,d\}$ is linearly independent?

To disprove this either we need to find one counterexample or we need to prove it. To prove let us suppose that $c_1a+c_2b+c_3c+c_4d=0$ then we need to show that $c_1=c_2=c_3=c_4=0$ .

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 'mutually independent elements', maybe you can clarify this?

Comment: @Matthias Klupsch : $S=\{a_1,\cdots a_k\}$ independent $\iff Vec(S)=k$

Comment: @nancy powel I don't think this is the good definition, because in this way $\{(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)\}$ for example would be "mutually independent elements" !

Comment: The answer to the question is no. Therefore, you just have to find a counterexample (but consider my definition of independence, not yours...)

Comment: @JeanMarie yes. If the given condition happens then any two distinct elements are linearly independent.

Comment: Here we are in $\mathbb R^5$ and the subset contains $4$ elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two given independences mean that $a,b,c$ and $a,b,d$ both span a subspace of dimension $3$, but it could be the same subspace in both cases. And it must be the same subspace if you want to find a counterexample, since two *different* subspaces of dimension $3$ would span a subspace of dimension (at least) $4$, and if $a,b,c,a,b,d$ spanned a subspace of dimension $4$ it would mean that $a,b,c,d$ are independent. The final independence just says that $c$ and $d$ are not scalar multiples of one another. So for a counterexample, try to find in a space $V$ of dimension$~3$ with a given subspace $W$ of dimension$~2$ (spanned by $a,b$), two vectors $c,d$ that lie outside the plane$~W$, and that are not scalar multiples of one another.

Comment: Yes. The example $\{e^1,e^2,e^3,e^2+e^3\}$ is working as a counterexample of  $\{a,b,c,d\}$. Thank you.